# What should be done to train the Reccurent neural network quickly?

Tags: r, time-series

I am fitting a recurrent neural network on the time series in R. I saw that many packages like `neuralnet`,  `nnet`,  and `RSNNS` are available for fitting the network to the given data.  `RSNNS` is especially used for fitting the recurrent neural networks. I have used this package with the commands `elman` and `jordan`.

I have 109 inputs which are huge. I will be having more inputs afterwards which will make the network more complex and naturally more time will be needed to train it.
The command goes like this

```
fit <- elman(nntrain[,2:110], nntrain[,1], size = c(20),
        learnFuncParams = c(0.01), maxit =1000)
```

It takes around 15 minutes to train the the network using above command which is huge. I have also tried using `neuralnet` command but that too takes big time.

```
nn <- nnet(f, data = nntrain, size = 20, linout = TRUE, maxit = 1000, decay = 0.01)
```

Command `nnet` takes comparatively low time to train the network but it cannot accommodate more weights and it shows error like this

> Error in nnet.default(x, y, w, ...) : too many (2221) weights

I have heard that recurrent neural networks are best to train time series if we have considerable inputs.
Is there any other command/package in R to train Recurrent neural networks in relatively less time and which can accommodate more inputs as well as more hidden nodes besides those commands I have mentioned?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: check out rnn package too!